# Is it possible to open a view displaying dataverse table's data on selecting a record from other table?

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps, dataverse, powerapps-modeldriven, model-driven-app

I'm creating model-driven application in MS Power Apps and I've the following use case:

I've 2 dataverse tables (Employee, Projects) where there's a relation between them 1:M,
and there's a lookup column in the projects table to identify the relation.

And I have a view for displaying all employees, on selecting any one of the employees, what happens is that it opens a view containing the details about this record I've selected.

But this is not what is intended to be done, what is needed is that on selecting an employee record, it displays a table containing all projects that he is working on.

So is there any way to create something to allow me to display a table showing all records based on selection from another table?

Answer (score 0):

Recently Microsoft delivered this long pending Wishlist item - [Power apps grid control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/model-driven-apps/the-power-apps-grid-control?WT.mc_id=5004422)

Follow [this blog](https://danikahil.com/2023/04/show-child-items-in-views-model-driven-apps.html) or [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HjrABElHSGo) for the configuration you are looking for. This feature may be in preview based on your region/version, hence not ready for Prod projects yet.

[image]

[Another option](https://d365goddess.com/nested-grids-in-dynamics-365/) is Editable grid which we used to do, but not the optimal solution.

Native option of leveraging the OOB behavior like below may suffice your need.

[image]